# How to show a ViewController (not modally) within a UITabViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabcontroller

I want to show a ViewController within a UITabController but not display it modally.   In the app, there's a home screen with a bunch of buttons that segue to other ViewControllers.   The other view controllers are embedded in a navigation controller.    I now have a need to show one of the ViewControllers from a TodayExtension.   In my app delegate I have this but it presents the RequestorViewContoller modally without the tab structure or the navigation control.

```
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let requestor = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RequestStoryboardID") as! RequestorViewController
    let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    rootViewController.present(requestor, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what you mention, if the `selectedViewController` of the `UITabBarController` is a `UINavigationController`, you could do a `pushViewController` instead.

First, you will have to get the currently on screen `UINavigationController`. Then perform a `pushViewController` with `requestor` as a parameter.

```
presentedNavigationController = rootViewController.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
presentedNavigationController.pushViewController(requestor, animated: true)
```

Comment: Great! Please make this as answered if is correct. =)